# .bat file to rename targeted folder for current user

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

Is it possible through Windows batch script to rename a specific folder for a user that is currently logged in?

I'm looking for renaming

```
C:\Users\current account name\AppData\Local\example name
```

to

```
example name.old
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable:

```
ren "%LOCALAPPDATA%\example name" "xample name.old"
```

Comment: Thanks! can't believe it was that easy haha.

Comment: you can type set into a command prompt and press enter to see all the set environment variables